# How to join 1.5 million rows of data based on 15 fields

Tags: excel, powerbi, dax, powerquery, powerpivot

I have a fact table of sales data from the year 2019, which has about 1.5 million rows of data. I need to compare 2019 sales with 2018 sales. The 2018 sales fact table also has about 1.5 million rows of data.

Each fact table has 15 of the same columns which include fields such as date, category, department, location, etc.

| Date | Field 1 | Field 2.. | …field 15 | Sales |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 01.01.18 | ABC | XYZ | A12 | 100 |
| 01.02.18 | ABCD | XXY | A13 | 200 |
| 01.03.18 | ABB | XYY | A14 | 300 |
| 01.04.18 | ACC | ZXX | A15 | 400 |

| Date | Field 1 | Field 2.. | …field 15 | Sales |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 01.01.19 | ABC | XYZ | A12 | 110 |
| 01.02.19 | ABCD | XXY | A13 | 210 |
| 01.03.19 | ABB | XYY | A14 | 310 |
| 01.04.19 | ACC | ZXX | A15 | 410 |

I need to have 2018 sales and 2019 sales in two columns that are next to each other.

I have tried this through a left join (matching the minimum amount of fields needed for a correct mapping) , but then my PC ran out of memory. I also tried doing this through power pivot, but my PC also ran out of energy while attempting to load the second fact table to the data model.

How can I have 2018 Sales and 2019 Sales, with the correct mapping, in columns next to each other?

| Date '18 | Date '19 | Field 1 | Field 2.. | …field 15 | Sales 2018 | Sales 2019 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 01.01.18 | 01.01.19 | ABC | XYZ | A12 | 100 | 110 |
| 01.02.18 | 01.02.19 | ABCD | XXY | A13 | 200 | 210 |
| 01.03.18 | 01.03.19 | ABB | XYY | A14 | 300 | 310 |
| 01.04.18 | 01.04.19 | ACC | ZXX | A15 | 400 | 410 |

Comment: There are a few things you can do to optimize joins in PQ; Chris Webb has a [series](https://blog.crossjoin.co.uk/tag/mergeperf/) on it. Ultimately, though, this is a lot of data, and you may need a "full" database engine to do the join, or else just get more memory. If the data is "complete", that is there are an identical number of rows in each table and no gaps, you can join based on row index after sorting, which should be faster.

Comment: Another option is pre-processing the fields that are to be joined on into a hash to join on that, but I don't think this is easy to do in PQ (there are no native functions), so you'd need Python or R for that processing step. At that point using a database where you can join in SQL becomes a more attractive option, though (a SQL Server LocalDB instance, for example).

Comment: Another thing to consider is to properly type all columns (if that hasn't already been done) and then to reduce text columns to types that consume less memory and compress better; in other words, create separate dimension tables for the column values and look up those, reducing your main fact tables to joins on integer fields. This is somewhat similar to the idea of hashing, but doable without invoking external code. It may require multiple passes over the data if there are not already suitable tables, though (and you may need to explicitly set the order of queries to not run out of memory).

Comment: Rather than doing a join, can't you use time intelligence functions to determine values 
 1 year ago? Union the tables and then split it down by filters, it can be done with a sumx measure rather that have two columns

Comment: I tried some of the things that I could implement from Chris Webb's series, those helped improve how much of the query was processed, but it was still far from finishing. The data set is not complete, and the time periods from 2018 and 2019 would need to be connected through a mapping table so that a proper comparison can be made. I created separate dimension tables, where it is possible, but that was also not enough for the join to work. 
I am not very familiar with time intelligence functions, so I am not entirely sure how I could implement those. Can those be implemented with a fiscal

Comment: year that begins with Oct 01 and ends Sept 30?

Comment: I unfortunately do not have access to a "full" data base engine, R, or Python for this project.

Comment: I'd probably combine then hash the 15 column if I had to do this in PQ, perhaps using one of these https://community.powerbi.com/t5/Desktop/Privacy-Hashing-of-keys/m-p/110574  Then its just one merge

Comment: I would strongly recommend against doing this as a join in the first place, if at all possible, and unioning/appending the tables instead. You can use measures/filters/relationships to look at the data rather than creating separate columns for separate years.

Comment: is the `fact table of sales data from the year 2019` located in the same sheet as 2018 ? if different.. what is the sheet name?

Comment: I tried combining the rows into one column and then merging the tables (without hashing, because this is something I do not have experience with yet, but I may try it again later with hashing) and only about 1/3 of it finished processing. I can append the tables and use measures/filters/relationships to show the data, but I wanted to see if I could solve this in Power Query before using Power Pivot, because I am more experienced with the former. The fact table of 2018 & 2019 sales are both in 2 separate .csv files.

Comment: If you have these in SQL server, it is piece of a cake. If not and you attempt to resolve this by using power query, you will run into severe performance issue. Try to solve this by building a data model, by using a `Calendar` table that filters a `Primary Key` Table that filters two `Fact Tables`...overall the your aim should be to build a `star schema`.  Also, use DAX measure and not calculated columns.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the csv data is imported to Sheet2(2018) & Sheet3(2019) via Data > Get External > From text. Put this in Sheet1 A1 :

```
=OFFSET(INDIRECT(CHOOSE(2-MOD(COLUMN(),2),"Sheet2","Sheet3")&"!A1",TRUE),ROW()-1,INT(COLUMN()/2+0.5)-1)
```

and drag right+downwards.

Idea : use `column()` with `mod()`, to 'drive' `offset` cell selection. `choose()` do the sheet selection.

Please share if it works/not. ( :